# Why does this test to check if there are any illegal characters in a string keep coming up as false even though it should be true?

Tags: delphi

```
var
btof: boolean;
const
  allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
begin
btof:= false;
for i := 1 to length(sfilename) do
  begin
    if (sfilename[i] in [allowed[1] .. allowed[length(allowed)]])
    then
      btof := true;
  end;
end;
```

I've been staring at this for the past hour trying to see the problem, but I just can't find it...
btof is always false, no matter the input.

Comment: That is not how you check if a character is in an string. Actually you check if the character is between 'a' and '9'. That's not really what you intent to do.

Comment: As you wrote it, allowed is a string constant. To make it a set, you could write it as "allowed=['a'..'z','A'..'Z', '0'..'9];" And then you could simply check "if sfilename[i] in allowed then"

Comment: If your task is to check filename, you may also look at `TPath.IsValidPathChar`, `TPath.IsValidFileNameChar`, maybe `TPath.HasValidFileNameChars` and/or others.

Answer (score 4):

The set notation `[allowed[1] .. allowed[length(allowed)]` boils down to a set of char `['a'..'9']`. As the literal `'9'` has a lesser value than the literal `'a'`, the resulting set is just empty.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you check if a character is in an string. Actually you check if the character is between 'a' and '9'. That's not really what you intent to do.

Here is an implementation that works:

```
// Check if a filename contain any illegal character
function CheckIllegal(const SFilename : String) : Boolean;
var
  C : Char;
const
  Allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  for C in SFilename do begin
      if Pos(C, Allowed) < 1 then begin
          Result := TRUE;
          break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

By the way, your list of allowed characters in a filename is incomplete, at least if you think about Windows OS.

Comment: `Pos(C, Allowed)` is a very inefficient way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
var
  bAllowed: boolean;
  sfilename: string;
  i, x: Integer;
  C: Integer;
const
  allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
begin
  bAllowed := true;
  sfilename := edtInput.Text;
  i := Length(sfilename);
  x := 1;
  while ((x <= i) and (bAllowed)) do
  begin
    bAllowed := Pos(sfilename[x], allowed) > 0;
    Inc(x);
  end;
  if bAllowed then
    ShowMessage('The string is valid')
  else
    ShowMessage('The string isn''t valid');
```

This is a more optimized version of the code. I take it that the purpose of the code that you gave was to determine if the string is valid and return a bool. Thus it only has to check up and till the point that it finds an illegal char in the string.

Note that I have changed it that if the string is valid it returns a true and invalid a false.

Comment: If it's about a filename then this code is wrong, as an empty filename should be invalid, too. (And as per target file system a max length also applies, which is not checked.)